# How to access the Selected Keys from a DropDownList in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to access the Selected Keys from two DropDowns and then call a Controller Action with the Keys as parameters.

In my MVC view I have then following code:

```
@model Test.Models.LoginViewModel
<p>
    Database @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDatabase, Model.DatabaseList, "-- Select an Item --", new {@id="databaseDD", @name="databaseDD"})
</p>
<p>
    Language @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedLanguage, Model.LanguageList, "-- Select an Item --", new {@id="languageDD", @name="languageDD"})
</p>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginToService", "Home", new { databaseKey = Model.SelectedDatabase, languageKey = Model.SelectedLanguage }, FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_self" }))
    {
        <input id="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    }
</p>
```

The problem is, the properties Model.SelectedDatabase and Model.SelectedLanguage are not set when the DropDown Selection changes. How can I access the Selected Keys and use them as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you should use a predefined class, something like this :

```
 public class DropDownItem
    {

        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
    }
```

Use a backend method to map desired fields to the DropDownItem something like:

```
    public SelectList FooListUsed()
    {
     List<DropDownItem> result =  from item in ListOfDataBaseTableElements
               select new DropDownItem{
                    Key = item.id,
                    Value = item.name
                     }
     result.Insert(0, new DropDownItem{ Key = 0, Value = "Select All" });
     return new SelectList(result, "Key", "Value"); //this mapping will take care of your selected value issue
```

Pass the result of the query to the view either through a Viewbag or through Model , 
lets use the viewbag for this example : `ViewBag.FooList=FooListUsed();`

Last step ... use your DropdownList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDatabase,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FooList)
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, my problem is not filling the DropDownList, but getting the Selected Key. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well your first problem is that you are not passing your values to a model. Your login button is included in a begin form .. but only what is defined into that begin form is pased back to a controller. First step would be including your dropdown list in the begin form .